# Indexed repositories within Artifactory

Tags: eclipse, maven-2, maven, m2eclipse, artifactory

Apologies if this is obvious to everyone else...

I've deployed the Artifactory war file within tomcat6 and started the server: all looks great.

Now, I want to navigate around the preconfigured repositories, for instance repro1-cache. However, it appears it's empty, there are no tree elements to expand. This appears to be the story for all the listed repositories. Consequently I cant run any searches for particular artifacts.

Am I missing a stage here? Do I need to force it to index itself? What should I be expecting once I've deployed the war file and when I first log in?

I guess my expectation was that once having deployed the war file, Artifactory would automatically index the remote repositories. I'd then configure Eclipse to point at the Artifactory install, so that it can index the repositories within the IDE. Then when I declare a new dependency, Artifactory would download and cache it locally, allowing for faster resolution next time. Is this a valid expectation?

Any feedback will be most appreciated, particularly any pointers to user documentation that covers this that I've overlooked.

Comment: Did you see log tomcat's log files?

Comment: There's nothing obvious in the tomcat logs.

Answer (score 4):

Your repositories are all empty because they aren't populated.
Once you deploy artifacts to the local repositories or request artifacts from remote repositories, you'll see them in the browser.

If you'd like to browse through artifacts not yet cached in remote repositories, you can use Artifactory's [simple browser](http://wiki.jfrog.org/confluence/display/RTF/Browsing+Artifactory) (see the Remote Browsing section).

Maven Indexes can be created and retrieved manually or as a recurring task; the Indexer can be configured in Artifactory's admin UI in *Admin->Services->Indexer* (also see the Indexer's [wiki page](http://wiki.jfrog.org/confluence/display/RTF/Exposing+Maven+Indexes)).

Comment: Thank you for this. What is still confusing me, is though I can indeed navigate via the simple view, I still dont see anything for the default 'repo1' (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2) repository? Also does, this mean I can only use the search facility for locally cached artifacts? And finally, my desire was to tie this all into the m2eclipse plugin, to allow easy search and configuration of dependencies, is this not possible with using Artifactory?

Comment: With remote browsing you should be able to see the actual contents of repo1 (or any other remote repository for that matter).
Yes, the search facilities only apply to the artifacts hosted in the local repositories or cached for the remote proxies.
For the m2eclipse plugin you need to generate Maven Indexes, as I've mentioned, once those indexes are generated\retrieved, Artifactory exposes them and they may be used by any consumer.